# Put list as arguments to elisp function

Tags: emacs, elisp

Ok, let's suppose we have a function like `format` in elisp:

```
(format "%s, %s" "Hello" "World!")  ;; returns "Hello, World!"
```

How can I get the same results if I have arguments as a list? In other words how to fix next form?

```
(equal "Hello, World!" (format "%s, %s" (list "Hello" "World")))
```

Comment: My guess is that there are essentially multiple duplicates of this question. Someone with time might want to search for them using, say, `[elisp] apply`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `apply`:

```
(apply 'format "%s, %s" (list "Hello" "World"))
```

`apply` accepts a function name (quoted), and then any number of "normal" arguments, and the final argument should be a list, that's appended after the "normal" arguments.